# Exclude dependencies by default in a library

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I have a multi submodule project, where some submodules depend on other submodules.

For example, with submodules a, b, c, and d,

```
b depends on a
c depends on b
d depends on a
```

As a result, if I have a separate project that needs b, c, and d, each of their respective R classes will hold a copy of the resources for module a. Is there a way to somehow exclude that so users don't have duplicate resources? The ids for the respective resources seem to stay consistent throughout the R class, so I'm not sure if they are actually being newly generated for each submodule.

One way is to use an @aar dependency, but that excludes all dependencies, including the ones that aren't duplicated. If possible, I'd like to avoid making users include those dependencies themselves.

Another way seems to be using `provided` rather than `compile`, but that isn't available for libraries.

The last way that I'm aware of is to have users exclude the sub dependencies in their gradle file, but again I'd like to try to manage that directly in the library if possible.

Are there any suggestions, or is this something I shouldn't be worrying about to begin with?

My actual library in question can be found [here](https://github.com/AllanWang/KAU), and you can see that there are quite a few interdependencies between the submodules.

A quick search shows that one of the attributes is added many many times:

[image]

Comment: There's only ever one copy of each resource. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Is it normal for me to see an attribute for my core submodule in so many R classes? And does it make a difference size wise if a person were to import each of my modules and exclude all the duplicate dependencies for each one? If that's normal then I guess there isn't anything to worry about.

Comment: @ianhanniballake The reason I'm asking this is because there are many libraries, like Glide for example, with extensions where they explicitly exclude the main dependency or set transitive to false because the other dependencies are "already included" in the main one. I would assume that this would affect the app size